# Why is Angular2 Router returning Observable

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I was wondering why [Angular2 Router](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) is returning Observables, forcing us to subscribe instead of just returning an array...

For example:

```
  // private router: ActivatedRoute
 this.router.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.router.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams) => { 
         this.router.url.subscribe((url) => { 
            // all logic code needs to be here after so many callbacks.....
          });
      });
 });
```

Comment: Because observables are awesome, and once you get your head wrapped around them, they provide a lot more power and flexibility.

Comment: what array do you expect? it will return you the values you pass into the parameters on the other page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the observable can emit the parameters multiple times. For example say you have this setup on a route of `/page/:pageNumber`

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.router.params.subscribe((params: {pageNumber: string}) => {
        // this callback is fired every time the parameters change
        this.pageNumber = params.pageNumber;
    });
}
```

and you load on `/page/1`. The ngOnInit runs only once on component load and you get your parameter `pageNumber = 1`. Now say you navigate to `/page/2`. You are still using the same component so ngOnInit does not fire again, however the the params observable detects the change and fires the callback again. This allows you to get the updated parameter `pageNumber = 2`

---

As Sasxa said, you can use routerSnapshot to get the parameters once.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.pageNumber = this.router.snapshot.params.pageNumber;
}
```

but now you lose the above functionality. When you navigate from `/page/1` to `/page/2`, ngOnit does not fire again so your `pageNumber` property is not updated to `2`. It all really depends on how you need to use the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get `ActivatedRoute` from [`RouterStateSnapshot`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterStateSnapshot)

```
let activated = this.router.routerState.shapshot.root;

while (activated.firstChild) {
   activated = activated.firstChild;
}

const { url, params, queryParams } = activated;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there are scenarios when components might be reused which means your route will change but you won't pickup change if you have static array which you read in `onInit` or something like that.
For that purposes, since your component instance stays alive, you need a way to get route parameters change. And that's what `Observable` is for.

ref:
https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse